# Running NextJs with Plesk throws an Error

Tags: npm, next.js, passenger, plesk

im currently trying to use my NextJs project with Plesk, but it always throws the following error in the Passenger log:

```
App 2825468 output: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
App 2825468 output: throw err;
App 2825468 output: ^
App 2825468 output:
App 2825468 output: Error: Cannot find module '../build/output/log'
App 2825468 output: Require stack:
App 2825468 output: - /var/www/vhosts/immatures.de/mysmug.immatures.de/node_modules/.bin/next
App 2825468 output: - /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js
App 2825468 output: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
App 2825468 output: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
App 2825468 output: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
App 2825468 output: at Module.require (/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 2825468 output: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
App 2825468 output: at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/immatures.de/mysmug.immatures.de/node_modules/.bin/next:7:35)
App 2825468 output: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
App 2825468 output: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
App 2825468 output: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
App 2825468 output: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) {
App 2825468 output: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
App 2825468 output: requireStack: [
App 2825468 output: '/var/www/vhosts/immatures.de/mysmug.immatures.de/node_modules/.bin/next',
App 2825468 output: '/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js'
App 2825468 output: ]
App 2825468 output: }
```

I've now tried for Hours to get it fixed, and deleted the node Modules several times.
I've also tried to use my local Nodejs Version (16.5), but then npm install fails with multiple dependency errors (now using NodeJs 14.20).

When trying to run NextJs as "Dev". it won't even start. The Passenger error only happens when setting "start" as the default command.

Any help regarding the Problem would be great!

Im using the following Application configuration:

```
Node.js-Version: 14.20.0  
Package Manager: npm    
Document Root: /mysmug.immatures.de/.next/static    
Application Mode: production  
Application URL: http://mysmug.immatures.de
Application Root: /mysmug.immatures.de    
Application Startup File: node_modules/.bin/next
```

Edit 1:
I just tried to "build & start" nextjs via the console. That works. But as soon as i start the Application via Plesk, it breaks and will give the same error, when trying to start it via console afterwards.

Reinstalling Node_Modules will fix the problem in the Terminal :/

Comment: hi, did you managed to find a solution to this Plesk issue? I been stuck for weeks, also getting `Error: Cannot find module '../build/output/log'` error